# Error when trying to run or build Flutter project for iOS Mac M1 chip

Tags: ios, flutter

So basically I can run other projects and I can run this one for Android but when I want to run it or build it for iOS I get the following error message

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...

Running pod install...                                             23.5s
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           28.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:

↳

```
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:

↳

```
/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/perm

ission_handler-5.0.0+hotfix.4/ios/Classes/strategies/PhotoPermissionStrategy

.m:39:13: warning: enumeration value 'PHAuthorizationStatusLimited' not

handled in switch [-Wswitch]

    switch (authorizationStatus) {

            ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/perm

ission_handler-5.0.0+hotfix.4/ios/Classes/strategies/PhotoPermissionStrategy

.m:39:13: note: add missing switch cases

    switch (authorizationStatus) {

            ^

1 warning generated.

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/perm

ission_handler-5.0.0+hotfix.4/ios/Classes/strategies/NotificationPermissionS

trategy.m:71:5: warning: 'UIRemoteNotificationType' is deprecated: first

deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's

UNAuthorizationOptions for user notifications and

registerForRemoteNotifications for receiving remote notifications instead.

[-Wdeprecated-declarations]

    UIRemoteNotificationType type = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]

    enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

    ^

In module 'UIKit' imported from

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Target Support

Files/permission_handler/permission_handler-prefix.pch:2:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor

m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra

mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:69:32: note: 'UIRemoteNotificationType' has

been explicitly marked deprecated here

typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIRemoteNotificationType) {

                               ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/perm

ission_handler-5.0.0+hotfix.4/ios/Classes/strategies/NotificationPermissionS

trategy.m:71:72: warning: 'enabledRemoteNotificationTypes' is deprecated:

first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use -[UIApplication

isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications] and UserNotifications Framework's

-[UNUserNotificationCenter getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:] to

retrieve user-enabled remote notification and user notification settings

[-Wdeprecated-declarations]

    UIRemoteNotificationType type = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]

    enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

                                                                       ^

In module 'UIKit' imported from

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Target Support

Files/permission_handler/permission_handler-prefix.pch:2:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor

m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra

mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:229:1: note: 'enabledRemoteNotificationTypes'

has been explicitly marked deprecated here

- (UIRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes

API_DEPRECATED("Use -[UIApplication isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications] and

UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter

getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:] to retrieve user-enabled

remote notification and user notification settings", ios(3.0, 8.0))

API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);

^

2 warnings generated.

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Reachability/Reachability.m:465:63: warning: cast to

smaller integer type 'unsigned int' from 'Reachability *'

[-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

                             NSStringFromClass([self class]), (unsigned int)

                             self, [self currentReachabilityFlags]];

                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                                                              ~~~~~

1 warning generated.

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:13

0:20: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a

prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

void GULResetLogger() {

                   ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:13

5:29: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a

prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

aslclient getGULLoggerClient() {

                            ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:13

9:35: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a

prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

dispatch_queue_t getGULClientQueue() {

                                  ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/GULLogger.m:14

3:27: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a

prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

BOOL getGULLoggerDebugMode() {

                          ^

4 warnings generated.

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRLogger.m:61:28:

warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype

[-Wstrict-prototypes]

void FIRLoggerInitializeASL() {

                           ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRLogger.m:104:20:

warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype

[-Wstrict-prototypes]

void FIRResetLogger() {

                   ^

2 warnings generated.

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/FirebaseDynamicLinks/FirebaseDynamicLinks/Sources/FIR

DLJavaScriptExecutor.m:29:51: warning: this old-style function definition is

not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

NSString *FIRDLTypeofFingerprintJSMethodNameString() {

                                                  ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/FirebaseDynamicLinks/FirebaseDynamicLinks/Sources/FIR

DLJavaScriptExecutor.m:39:39: warning: this old-style function definition is

not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

NSString *GINFingerprintJSMethodString() {

                                      ^

2 warnings generated.

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Firebase/InstanceID/FIRInstanceIDV

ersionUtilities.m:33:45: warning: this old-style function definition is not

preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

void FIRInstanceIDParseCurrentLibraryVersion() {

                                            ^

1 warning generated.

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/FIRMessag

ingTopicOperation.m:29:42: warning: this old-style function definition is

not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

NSString *FIRMessagingSubscriptionsServer() {

                                         ^

1 warning generated.

In file included from

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fire

base_messaging-8.0.0-dev.11/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:9:

In file included from

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fire

base_messaging-8.0.0-dev.11/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.h:11:

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:45:10: warning:

"FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add

`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to

your project to ensure Firebase Dynamic Links works as intended."

[-W#warnings]

        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your

        target. Please add \

         ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:79:10: warning:

"FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add

`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to

your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended." [-W#warnings]

        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your

        target. Please add \

         ^

2 warnings generated.

In file included from

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fire

base_dynamic_links-0.6.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.m:7:

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:45:10: warning:

"FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add

`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to

your project to ensure Firebase Dynamic Links works as intended."

[-W#warnings]

        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your

        target. Please add \

         ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:79:10: warning:

"FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add

`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to

your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended." [-W#warnings]

        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your

        target. Please add \

         ^

2 warnings generated.

While building module 'firebase_messaging' imported from

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:38:

While building module 'Firebase' imported from

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_messaging/firebase_me

ssaging.framework/Headers/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.h:11:

In file included from <module-includes>:1:

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:45:10: warning:

"FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add

`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to

your project to ensure Firebase Dynamic Links works as intended."

[-W#warnings]

        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your

        target. Please add \

         ^

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:79:10: warning:

"FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add

`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to

your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended." [-W#warnings]

        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your

        target. Please add \

         ^

2 warnings generated.

2 warnings generated.

2 warnings generated.

2021-10-28 10:27:16.391 ibtoold[2301:28247] DEBUG: Added to environment: {

    TMPDIR =

    "/var/folders/6p/m59nz_056zl0_v3d2wbhvnhm0000gn/T/67E935D1-846D-4135-B3F

    7-C3AC3A7412F6";

}

/* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][iphone][76x

76][][][2x][][][2d][Icon-App-76x76@2x.png]: warning: The app icon set

"AppIcon" has an unassigned child.

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][iphone][76x

76][][][2x][][][2d][Icon-App-76x76@2x.png]: warning: The app icon set

"AppIcon" has an unassigned child.

/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76

][][][1x][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting

releases of iOS prior to 10.0.

/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@2x.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@2x~ipa

d.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@3x.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20~ipad.p

ng

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@2x~ipa

d.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@3x.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29~ipad.p

ng

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@2x.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipa

d.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@3x.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.p

ng

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@3x.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipa

d.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.p

ng

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon83.5x83.5@2x

~ipad.png

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Assets.car

/Users/vidyajagtap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-byiaydlbyhakun

czxlioctifsuzy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulato

r/Runner.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist



/Users/vidyajagtap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-byiaydlbyhakun

czxlioctifsuzy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulato

r/Runner.build/Script-17680BAF24D09B0E005B76D2.sh: line 3:

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Fabric/run: No such file or directory

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

note: Using new build system

note: Building targets in parallel

note: Planning build

note: Analyzing workspace

note: Constructing build description

note: Build preparation complete

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment

target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of

supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target

'webview_flutter' from project 'Pods')

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment

target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of

supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target

'wakelock' from project 'Pods')

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment

target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of

supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target

'video_player' from project 'Pods')

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment

target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of

supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target

'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')

/Users/vidyajagtap/Documents/Vidya/Xirify_Project/asap-marketplace-mobile/xi

rify-shopping/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment
```

Comment: Your error log is incomplete. One reason for error can be because of deployment target. In xcode, select the project runner and change the deployment target from 8.0 to 9.0 or above. You can search 'deployment target' in search box under build settings.